# Wacom Cintiq 22”?

Tags: grease-pencil, sculpt

I wanna buy a display tablet for 3d/2d, and the max I can afford is the **Wacom Cintiq 22"**

my choice is limited because of the way I’ll pay for it (voucher+cash) which is only supported by a few local stores

- can it run blender ? or is its display an **extension or duplicate of my computer display ?**
- does **anyone have xp with this product ?** I heard it is good and Wacom is recommended for **compatibility reasons**
- I heard **parallax issues should be taken into account**, and should be limited with this model

thanks for your guidance

my pc :

- Geforce gtx1080
- Win 10 Home
- 16gb ram
- Intel® QUAD Core i7-6700K 4.00 GHz

Comment: This isn't a question about Blender, but you might be able to find another stack exchange  site that is more suitable. To answer part of your question: It's basically a fancy monitor, so yes, it will work with Blender just like your current monitor does.

Comment: how do you mean "find another stack exchange site" ??? is there a more blender/hardware related stackexchange site ?

Comment: it's a really big investment, I just don't wanna screw that up

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place for a question like this.

Comment: thx...yet I got that feeling the first comment popping up, will tell me to come back here :-) I'll wait for better suggestions

Comment: Hi, [hardwarerecs.se](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this q, hardware recommendations are considered [off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) here.

Comment: then I am gone...thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, display tablets are usually just fancy monitors that can detect a pen.
So you can 'run' blender or pretty much anything on it.

EDIT:

To make things as clear as possible:
The tablet connects to a computer as a display.
So without a computer it is pretty useless obviously.
If you want to run blender or any software on it, you need to run it on your computer.
The tablet will use a second connection (Typically usb) to tell the computer what your pen or finger (some tablets only detect one of both) is doing on the tablet.

Comment: I think in the context of the question you can't "run" any software on it, you still need a working computer connected to the tablet

Comment: yes as far as I understand, nothing runs on the table itself, it's a screen (I did'nt know that at the time I wrote the question)